# how to secure JWT both client and server

Tags: security, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using JWT authentication for my back-end system written with Django rest frame work,
I've read many articles about JWT security but I have some question yet,
our solution for not saving the access token in browsers local was that we save the refresh token in cookie and client request access token with this cookie in every request for not saving access token anywhere,is this approach save enough?
what can I do for server side?for example is using dynamic secret key for JWT a good idea?
I mean create an secret key for each user and use it for token.or any idea that can secure our system.

Comment: That approach is nonesense, of course the access token should be stored client side. And no, a distinct key for reach user is also not needed, your or not following any best practices at all here. Have one key that you use to sign the token, store that token on the client side and let the client send it along on each request. 
What attack if any are your worried about and how is your current approach solving those?

Comment: I've read many docs mention that saving access token in local storage of browser is not a good idea,so we need that for authenticate the requests,what we can do instead?

Comment: Store it in a cookie. Either http-only or not.

Comment: can you explain me why it's more safe than local storage?

Comment: javascript cannot access http-only cookies and therefore even a rouge client side script cannot steal the access token.

Comment: What will the scenario be like?client need the access token to put it on auth header of each request and refresh token to create new access token. What will be if can't access the data on that cookie

Comment: Cookies are automatically sent with each request, just not in the auth. header. The refresh token can be scoped to just the refresh token endpoint, the JavaScript never sees any token but the request it submits will have them.